# Click sound from computer when shut down

Tags: audio, shutdown

I build my new computer yesterday and I noticed, when computer is shut down, I mean the exact time its looses power from PSU, relativelly loud CLICK sound occurs. Please does anyone knows from where? I think MB, SSD, VGA, CPU nor coolers are not cousing this.

I would guess maybe Samsung 1TB HDD (maybe when heads go back to LZ) or some hard safety switch or relay in PSU? Or just the MB speaker? (Yes, its actually installed).

Do you have any experience with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the most likely cause is either the built in speaker or the hard drive.

I use a lot of Intel boards which have the built in speakers and I often hear a rather loud clicking noise when the computer is turned off.

Comment: Well, so I disconnect it :)

Comment: Just don't turn off your computer!

Answer (score 0):

HDD, PSU, or speaker sound like the only likely culprits. You could try disconnecting components until the sound goes away and then you'd have your answer.

Comment: Well, I am pretty dissapointed with HDD, becouse its really loud, even louder than my previous Samsung HDD 400GB so maybe its it....